# A match is found but how do I extract the data?

Tags: java, regex

I have following regex `(abc|def)( ?(\\d+|(?:(?!\\1)[a-z])+)?)*` with matches perfectly the subject `abc123 456`.
Now I want to get all parts *abc*, *123* and *456*.

I use following code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(subject);

while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

But so I get only `abc123 456`.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: While I haven't analyzed the whole pattern, this looks overly complicated. In particular, in `(abc|def|[a-z]+)` the `[a-z]+` part will match "abc" or "def" so listing them as alternatives makes no difference.

Comment: I have forgotten to use the actual pattern. ;) Now it is correct.

Comment: the pattern might match the input fine, but does it match the groups correctly?

Comment: Yes it works, but I notice that I can simplify the regex. abc|def are commands and then there are the parameters seperated by space. And I search for a way to get them. But I think it is easier to cut off the command and split by space, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the solution explained in my comment above:

> Yes it works, but I notice that I can
>   simplify the regex. abc|def are
>   commands and then there are the
>   parameters seperated by space. And I
>   search for a way to get them. But I
>   think it is easier to cut off the
>   command and split by space, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to get each group individually instead of `m.group()`. The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()) states that `m.group()` is equivalent to `m.group(0)`, and individual groups can be accessed with the `m.group(int)` version. So the following assertions should reflect the grouping as you expect.

```
Assert.assertEquals("abc", m.group(1));
Assert.assertEquals("123", m.group(2));
Assert.assertEquals("456", m.group(3));
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. m.group(1) gives back abc, m.group(2) nothing and m.group(3) 456. So I don't get what I want. I want to get all three parts alone.